# Some mistakes in drawing 3D curves

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Here are three pieces of code that can draw 3D curves and are successfully used for {x^2 + y^2 == 1, 2*x + 3*z == 6}:

(1)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
h =x^2 + y^2 -1;
g =2*x + 3*z - 6;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 4}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

(2)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, 2*x + 3*z == 6}, {x, y, z}];
Region[reg, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 4}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

(3)

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, 
    2*x + 3*z == 6}, {x, #, #2}, {y, #3, #4}, {z, #5, #6}, Mesh -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> 18, ViewPoint -> {5, 1, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> (Directive @@@ {{Red}, {Green}, {Blue, 
        Opacity@.3}, {Yellow}}), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}] & @@@ {{-2, 2, -2, 2, 0, 4}}
```

However, there are some errors when drawing 3D curves {z == Sqrt[16 - x^2 - y^2], (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 4}:

(1)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
h = z - Sqrt[16 - x^2 - y^2];
g = (x - 2)^2 + y^2 - 4;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

(*The surface has some irregular bulges and some irregular curves*)

(2)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{z == Sqrt[16 - x^2 - y^2], (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 
     4}, {x, y, z}];
Region[reg, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 5}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

(*The curve cannot be seen*)

(3)

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
ContourPlot3D[{z == Sqrt[16 - x^2 - y^2], (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 
     4}, {x, #, #2}, {y, #3, #4}, {z, #5, #6}, Mesh -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> 18, ViewPoint -> {5, 1, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> (Directive @@@ {{Red}, {Green}, {Blue, 
        Opacity@.3}, {Yellow}}), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}] & @@@ {{-1, 5, -3, 3, -1, 5}}
```

(*The underside of the surface is not smooth*)

How to solve these problems?

Answer (score 5):

One way is avoid `Sqrt`.

```
Clear[reg];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{z^2 == 16 - x^2 - y^2, (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 
    4}, {x, y, z}]
Region[Style[reg, Directive[Thick, Red]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 5}}, 
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[{z^2 == 16 - x^2 - y^2, (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 
     4}, {x, #, #2}, {y, #3, #4}, {z, #5, #6}, Mesh -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ViewPoint -> {5, 1, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> (Directive @@@ {{Red}, {Green}, {Blue, 
        Opacity@.3}, {Yellow}}), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotPoints -> 50] & @@@ {{-1, 5, -3, 
   3, -1, 5}}
```

```
Clear[h, g];
h = z^2 - (16 - x^2 - y^2);
g = (x - 2)^2 + y^2 - 4;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. z>0. The region should be" ImplicitRegion[{z^2 == 16 - x^2 - y^2, (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 4, z > 0}, {x, y, z}]". But how to set the function value to Z > 0 in ContourPlot3d? @cvgmt

Comment: @lotus2019 Remove `PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 5}}`

Comment: Thank you. How to set the function value to Z > 0 in ContourPlot3D?@cvgmt

Comment: @lotus2019  `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, z}, z > 0], RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`

Comment: Thank you! @cvgmt